# How to include the path needed by C++ in cython?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I managed to get Cython working for a simple C++ file. But when I tried to get it to work for our project, I got a path issue.

When I run "python3.6 setup.py build_ext --inplace", I got these errors:

```
myapp.h:12:10: fatal error: base/file1.h: No such file or directory
 #include <base/file1.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
.
|-- base
|   |-- file1.h
|   \-- file1.cpp
|
|-- app
|   |-- app.pyx
|   \-- setup.py
|
|-- myapp.cpp
\-- myapp.h
```

Here is the setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
    "app",
    sources=["app.pyx", "myapp.cpp"],
    language="c++",
)))
```

In myapp.h, there is this line:

```
#include <base/file1.h>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with #include <base/file1.h>. Try please changing to #include "base/file1.h". You are using custom local header file, so the double quotes.

Comment: Good point. I tried. It complains the same thing.

Comment: „Configuring the c build“ section in https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html

Comment: You need to tell your compiler where to search for includes. For GCC and Clang this is done with the `-I` switch. For the Visual Studio compiler it's something else (but similar). You need to configure your biild system properly.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `include_dirs` parameter of setup. In your case, this should work:

```
setup(...
    include_dirs = ['.'],
     ... )
```

Or maybe `'..'`, your directory tree is a bit unusual.